# Not able to add custom API in PowerApps as Custom Connector

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, powerapps, office365connectors

**Issue:** Custom connector in PowerApps by calling Azure API management

**Platform:** Office 365
I have a sample webapp where I have deployed my test WebAPI into it. when I test normally by accessing URL with /api/values which is working fine. Now I want to add this as connector to my PowerApp to access web API. I have done following things to achieve this

1. Created API Management for this web app.
2. Created new API. I have tested this and showing results as desired.
3. I went to PowerApps and trying to create a custom connector using "Create from Azure service (preview)" option.
4. I have selected my subscription details and my api management name but when I select my custom API it is giving below error. But when I select default api which is echo-api then there is no issue. What would be the resolution for this
   [image]

Is there anything to do at Visual Studio solution level?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, the description in 200 response of the `GET` request is of type 'Null'. You should modify it to type 'String'.

[image]

Then change it to `""` or other meaningful string.

[image]

You may will be required to do the same thing for other requests.

Comment: Thanks. Will try this